# Rails 3.1 - Binding HABTM from other controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, has-and-belongs-to-many, has-many-through

I have:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :people_phones
  has_many :phones, :through => :people_phones
end
```

I also have:

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :phone
end
```

Now when someone call with a request I open "requests#new" form, fill in person_id and phone_number and other details and submits them to "requests#create" controller#action.

In the "requests#create", I can do:

```
@phone = Phone.find_or_create_by_phone_number(params[:phone][:phone_number])
```

But how can I bind Person with that Phone from this Requests controller?

I mean create a record in people_phones table (if it doesn't exists)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User.find(person_id).phones << @phone
```

I don't really know how your app works, but you see the idea.
If you have a request, and you want to "validate" it, you would do

```
request.person.phones << request.phone
```

---

Interesting stuff to know, it's kind of related (I'll try to find where I found that, it was a long time ago)

Steps required for the object to be saved to database:

New

```
Blog.new(…).save
user.blogs << Blog.new(…)
user.blogs.new(…).save – do not use, no practical use case
```

Build

```
Blog.build – not possible
user.blogs.build(…), user.save – both are required to save to DB
```

Create

```
Blog.create(…)
user.blogs.create(…)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've never seen this "<<" operator and I am not successful googling it. What does it exactly do?

Comment: `<<` is used in ruby to add an element to an array. It's the same principle here, except that it then saves the object to the database. I will edit my answer with some details.